# QTreeView with QAbstractItemModel and parent not known in the datamodel

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, qmodelindex

I want to use QTreeView to visualize my class hierarchy. That hierarchy is given and I couldn't change it. But QAbstractItemModel force me to implement a parent() method in it. How can I do that?

So I have:

```
class ItemA
{
  std::vector<Items1> items1;
  std::vector<Items2> items2;
  std::vector<Items3> items3;
};

class Items2
{
  std::vector<Items1X> items1X;
  std::vector<Items2X> items2X;
  std::vector<Items3X> items3X;
};

...
```

How can I implement a `QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const;` method for `QAbstractItemModel`?

Comment: How do you implement the `index(int, int, const QModelIndex &)` function of your model?

Comment: `parent` must return the parent item index for a given item index. You have that information. What's the problem?